# How does one find and set localhost, user and password when using MySQL entirely through command line on Linux server, and not through phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql

I bought a 5$ Digital Ocean droplet in order to host and tinker with my projects, however, I'm facing some unexpected problems.

I installed MySQL through the command line and cloned my project from git, but I quickly realized that I need to connect to the database using the right credentials. Usually, I just go to `phpMyAdmin` and just copy the user and host from their interface but now that I'm using MySQL through the command line, I can't do that.

The error I'm getting is:

```
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"
```

So I assume either my user or host is wrong. I'm trying to figure out how to find the correct values.

Comment: What is the command you are using to connect on the command line?

Comment: @JorgeCampos To connect to MySQL? sudo mysql

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html ?

Comment: Pretty much what @BillKarwin just posted will help you out.

Comment: Thank you fellas! I did that and it worked out! I think that there was something wrong with my root user ( or I changed something while tinkering ), because once I dropped and recreated the new user, it worked like a charm.